# Normalize a Table That Contains Monthly, Yearly and Quarterly Data

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

How do I normalize this table:

```
Frequency (PK)    Year (PK)    Quarter (PK)    Month (PK)    Value
Monthly           2013         1               1             1
Quarterly         2013         1               0             2
Yearly            2013         0               0             3
```

The table is not in 2nd normal form, because when Frequency = Yearly Value depends on a subset of the primary key (Frequency, Year)

I've thougt about adding a surrogate key. Then Quarter and Month columns could be nullable.

```
Surrogate (PK)    Frequency    Year    Quarter     Month     Value
1                 Monthly      2013    1           1         1
2                 Quarterly    2013    1           NULL      2
3                 Yearly       2013    NULL        NULL      3
```

But this doesn't solve the problem, because the 2nd normal form definition also applies to candidate keys. Dividing the table into three tables based on Frequency doesn't sound like a good idea, because it will introduce if statemments into my business logic:

```
if (frequency == Monthly) then select from DataMonthly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This table could do probably without the `[Frequency]` and `[Quarter]` column.

Why do you want to have these in? Is there any added value in having the Quarterly and Yearly values precalculated in this table? *Comment: Since it's Value's are not just the sum of it's Month's*.

So `[Quarter]` is mandatory.

This will work too:

```
Year (PK)    Quarter (PK)    Month (PK)    Value
2013         1               1             1
2013         1               0             2
2013         0               0             3
```

Yearly results:

```
SELECT 
    [Value] 
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [Year] = 2013 AND [Quarter] = 0 AND [Month] = 0
```

Quarterly results:

```
SELECT 
    [Value]
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [Year] = 2013 AND [Quarter] = 1 AND [Month] = 0
```

Monthly results:

```
SELECT 
    [Value] AS [Results] 
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [Year] = 2013 AND [Quarter] = 1 AND [Month] = 1
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: The Yearly value is not just a sum of monthly values. Statistical formulas are used that I don't know about.

Comment: That's valid. Added the Quarter-column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that a couple of year's worth of data might look something like this. Correct me if I'm wrong. (I'm going to ignore the issue of whether using zeroes is a good idea or a bad idea.)

```
Frequency    Year    Quarter     Month     Value
--
Monthly      2012    1           1         1
Monthly      2012    1           2         2
Monthly      2012    1           3         3
Monthly      2012    2           4         4
Monthly      2012    2           5         5
Monthly      2012    2           6         6
Monthly      2012    3           7         7
Monthly      2012    3           8         8
Monthly      2012    3           9         9
Monthly      2012    4           10        10
Monthly      2012    4           11        11
Monthly      2012    4           12        12
Quarterly    2012    1           0         2
Quarterly    2012    2           0         5
Quarterly    2012    3           0         8
Quarterly    2012    4           0         11
Yearly       2012    0           0         3
Monthly      2013    1           1         1
Monthly      2013    1           2         2
Monthly      2013    1           3         3
Monthly      2013    2           4         4
Monthly      2013    2           5         5
Monthly      2013    2           6         6
Monthly      2013    3           7         7
Monthly      2013    3           8         8
Monthly      2013    3           9         9
Monthly      2013    4           10        10
Monthly      2013    4           11        11
Monthly      2013    4           12        12
Quarterly    2013    1           0         2
Quarterly    2013    2           0         5
Quarterly    2013    3           0         8
Quarterly    2013    4           0         11
Yearly       2013    0           0         3
```

From that data we can deduce two functional dependencies. A functional dependency answers the question, "Given one value for the set of attributes 'X', do we know one and only one value for the set of attributes 'Y'?"

- {Year, Quarter, Month}->Frequency
- {Year, Quarter, Month}->Value

Given one value for the set of attributes {Year, Quarter, Month}, we know one and only one value for the set of attributes {Frequency}. And given one value for the set of attributes {Year, Quarter, Month}, we know one and only one value for the set of attributes {Value}.

The problem you were running into involved including "Frequency" as part of the primary key. It's really not.